# Compare cell contents against string in Excel

Tags: string, excel, if-statement, comparison

Consider the following:

```
    A   B
1  ENG  1
2  ENG  1
3  FRA  0
4  FOO  0
```

I need a formula to populate the `B` column with `1` if the `A` column contains the string `ENG`, or `0` otherwise.

I've tried (in cell B1) `=IF(A1=(TEXT(ENG;FALSE));1;0)` but then it says `#NAME?` in the cell. Putting `ENG` between quotation marks doesn't help either. What should my formula be like?

Comment: Can you have a situation where Cell in Col can have `Blah ENG` or ` ENG ` (notice the space)

Comment: nope...it's always exactly `ENG`

Comment: So why not `=if(a1="ENG",1,0)` or `=if(a1="ENG";1;0)` if using a NON US version?

Comment: D*mn, thanks. I'm usually scripting in languages making "==" type comparisons. I kept getting an error using "==" in Excel so instead of taking the obvious course I was looking for some excel-specific function to make string-comparisons...thanks

Comment: @Pr0no, select an answer as correct.

Answer (score 28):

You can use the `EXACT` Function for exact string comparisons.

```
=IF(EXACT(A1, "ENG"), 1, 0)
```

Comment: To made this answer clearer, and for those coming here with Python/SQL backgrounds, it MUST be double quoted. Unlike python and many other languages, single quotes will give you an error. That was my issue which I often forget.

Answer (score 10):

If a case-insensitive comparison is acceptable, just use `=`:

```
=IF(A1="ENG",1,0)
```